# How do I find the equation of the normal to $y = x^2 - 3x +2$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

The question I got first asked me to solve the simultaneous equation:
$y = x^2 - 3x +2$ and
$y = 3x - 7$

then hence or otherwise find the equation of the normal of $y = x^2 - 3x +2$ at one point $(3,2)$. Giving the answer in the form of $ax + by + c =0$

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

When solving the system of equations, you'll obtain a quadratic with exactly one real solution at $x = 3$. This implies that the given line is actually tangent to the given parabola.

Coincidentally, the second part of the question asks for the normal line at $x = 3$. Since perpendicular lines have slopes that multiply to be $-1$, and the slope of the tangent line is $3$, it follows that the slope of the normal line is its negative reciprocal, $-1/3$. Using the point-slope formula, we have:
$$
y - 2 = \frac{-1}{3}(x - 3)
$$
It remains to convert this to the form $ax + by + c = 0$ by clearing the fraction and bringing all terms to one side.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* How many solutions do you get for the system of equations? What does this tell you about the line $y=3x-7$?

Answer (score 0):

**First Part**

To solve simultaneously you can equate the two equations.

$$x^2-3x+2=3x-7$$

$$x^2-6x+9=0$$

$$(x-3)^2=0$$

$$x-3=0$$

$$x=3$$

Hence:

$$y=3\times3-7=2$$

**Second Part**

As the system only has one solution then the line and the parabola meet at only one point. This is only possible when the line is a tangent. Conveniently the given line goes through $(3,2)$. Hence the equation of the tangent through $(3,2)$ is:

$$y=-3x+2$$

$$3x+y-2=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's first look at the first two equations
$$(y = 3x-7)\text{ -  1 eqn}$$
$$(y = x^2-3x+2)\text{ - 2 eqn}$$

By substituting the value of y from the first to the second we get
$$ 3x-7 = x^2 -3x +2$$
$$0 = x^2 -6x +9$$
Through factoring from middle term splitting we get
$$0 = x^2 -3x -3x +9$$
$$0 = x(x-3) -3(x-3)$$
$$0 = (x-3)^2$$
Hence we get the value
$$ x = 3 $$
By putting this value in any one of the above equations we can get
$$ y = 3x-7 $$
$$ y = 2 $$
Hence the solution to this equation is $(3,2)$

Answer (score -1):

I assume that ''2Y'' part is a typo? Solving that equation is as follows:

- x^2-6x+9=0
- (x-3)^2 = 0
- x=3

For the hence/otherwise part

- dy/dx = 2x - 3
- Substitute in the x co-ordinate to get the gradient of it at the specified point. (which is x = 3)
- M(Tangent) = 3, therefore, M(Normal) = -1/3
- y= -1/3x + c, sub in point
- c= 3
- Therefore -> y= -1/3x + 3 (Multiply both sides by 3)
- 3y= -x + 9
- 3y + x - 9 = 0 (as specified in the question)

Therefore, equation to the normal is 3y + x - 9 = 0

Comment: But isn't this precalculus? So how can you find the derivative?

Comment: The "2 Y" isn't a typo. Its just poor spacing between the two equations.

Comment: Fair call fellas, you are way above me in the food chain.